# What's best way to update Meteor CLI?

Tags: meteor, command-line-interface

Just trying to update Meteor CLI from version `1.12` to `1.12.1` but in general, what's the best way to update Meteor's CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To specifically update the Meteor CLI, without having to update a meteor project as well, you can move into any folder that is not a Meteor project folder and run the `meteor update` command

Comment: interesting... I tried running the install cmd again `curl https://install.meteor.com/ | sh` but it failed, and I had to `rm -rf ~/.meteor/packages` first... but even then `meteor --version` gave me the old version.... however `meteor update` works! I ran it and `meteor --version` gives me `1.12.1` !  Thanks.

Comment: If you run `meteor --version` within a project directory it will tell you the version of meteor to which that project is pinned. If you run the same command outside of a meteor project directory, it will tell you the most current version that is installed

Answer (score 2):

There are several kinds of update:

1. downloading the newest Meteor tool
2. updating the *current project* to the latest Meteor tool version (implies 1.)
3. updating all packages to their latest versions

You can all manage that by using the `meteor update` command with (or without) the respective flags, like `--patch`, `--packages-only` or `--all-packages`.

See: https://docs.meteor.com/commandline.html#meteorupdate

You can also type `meteor update --help` for information on the respective flags.

Answer (score 1):

Definitely no need to re-install the tool. Running `meteor update` outside of the meteor project does update just the command line, but you should be really updating your project by running `meteor update --release <version>` in your project folder.